# Error with my code, returns incorrect result

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def test_code(message):
    msg_list = message.split(',')
    for item in msg_list:
        empty_dict = {}
        if item.find('=') != -1:
            split_str = [char.strip("'") for char in msg_list[
                msg_list.index(item)].split('=')]
            if split_str[1].find('.') != -1:
                empty_dict.update({'test': [1, 2]})
            else:
                empty_dict.update({'test': [3, 4]})
        elif item.find('>') != -1:
            split_str = [char.strip("'") for char in msg_list[
                msg_list.index(item)].split('>')]
            if split_str[1].find('.') != -1:
                empty_dict.update({'test': [5, 6]})
            else:
                empty_dict.update({'test': [7, 8]})
        return empty_dict
```

So what my code does it this:

It takes a string as an input in the format: a.name=o.name,a.year>o.year
it splits it at the comma and gives:
['a.name=o.name','a.year>o.year']
now it loops through each item in the list, and if it finds a '=' character in the item
it splits the item at the '=' character and gives this:
['a.name', 'o.name']
now, if the 1'st index has a '.' in it(which in this case o.name does), it updates the empty list with {'test': [1,2]}
if it doesnt have a . than it updates the dictionary with {'test': [3,4]}

Now the empty_dict = {'test': [1,2]}

It now moves on to the next item in the list which is 'a.year>o.year', and if it finds a
'>' character in the list then it splits it at the >. We get:

['a.year', 'o.year']

if the element at index one has a '.' it updates the list with {'test': [5,6]}, else it updates with {'test: [7,8]}

Now when I run my code on this:

```
>> test_code("a.name=o.name,a.year>o.year")
{'test': [1, 2]}
```

which isn't correct it should give, {'test': [5, 6]}

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please don't edit out your code and add "solved" to the title.  By accepting an answer, you have already marked the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return`has too much indent. You're returning after the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

`return` should be at the same indent of `def` , otherwise you will return the value for every `item`